# Could not activate Windows 10 upgrade from Pro to Enterprise using Office 365 E3 license

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-10, entra-id

Our Setup:

- Windows 10 Pro 1803 local AD joined.
- Local domain synced with Azure AD \ Office 365.
- Users have Office 365 E3 licenses.

We have Office 365 E3 licenses, which include Windows 10 Enterprise. I have tried to upgrade from Windows 10 Pro to Enterprise edition using these steps:

https://aadguide.azurewebsites.net/aadjoin/
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-enterprise-licenses

Some Troubleshooting :

1. dsregcmd /status shows  AzureAdJoined status is YES; also this desktop is showing in Azure AD Portal.
2. Could not find any Task Scheduler 
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/enroll-a-windows-10-device-automatically-using-group-policy#task-scheduler-app

Tried  troubleshooting steps as per following URLs, but still could not find any clue:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/78afe9a3-3449-4efb-bf20-e3ad5f2b32a2/windows-10-e3-csp-activation-with-hybird-azure-ad-join?forum=win10itprosetup

Comment: Office 365 E3 comes with "24/7 phone support for all IT issues. For less urgent issues, you can make service requests directly through the admin portal." https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-for-business-support-options

Comment: It also does not come with Windows licensing. Seems that what it comes with is customers not reading what they did buy.

Comment: Do you maybe have Microsoft 365 E3? - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/microsoft-365-enterprise.aspx

Comment: He may mean that, but this is a professional place for professional people and we generally are free to assume you know what you talk of and are smart enough to write down a product name ;) That said, it is posible that this is the mixup which happened in purchasing ;)

Answer (score 3):

@TomTom is correct here.  Office 365 and Enterprise Mobility subscriptions do not include Windows licensing.

Windows Enterprise is included with the following subscriptions:

- Windows Enterprise E3
- Windows Enterprise E5
- Microsoft 365 E3
- Microsoft 365 E5

You can also purchase the license through traditional volume licensing channels as well. With the Subscription model, you also receive access to Windows Defender Advance Threat Protection.

Answer (score 2):

> We have Office 365 E3 License which gives Windows 10 Enterprise

Ah, no?

Not per https://products.office.com/en/business/office-365-enterprise-e3-business-software or https://products.office.com/en/business/compare-more-office-365-for-business-plans

And it is not "Office 365 with E3". It is "Office 365 E3". E3 is the variant of the plan.

Comment: Yes , We have Office 365 E3 , it was typo error , Do you know the Solution of the Problem i Described

Comment: Yes. Get licenses. Upgrade to Microsoft 365 (which includes windwos AND Office 365). What solution outside of "pay for your licenses" do you want?